# I change the last line in /etc/passwd and I can't use sudo

Tags: command-line, login, password, sudo

Here is what I have done:

1. Change a username in the last line: `tiny` to `abc`

   - `tiny@tty7:~$ sudo vim /etc/passwd`
   - Change this:
     `tiny:x:1000:1000:tiny,,,:/home/tiny:/bin/bash`
     to this:
     `abc:x:1000:1000:tiny,,,:/home/tiny:/bin/bash`
2. `tiny@tty7:~$ sudo vim /etc/shadow`

   - it shows: `[sudo] passwork for abc:`
   - **I didn't change my password but it can't login root!**
   - I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to `tty1` but neither **tiny** or **abc** can't login with my password

and I try to look at `ls ～ -la`, here it shows like this:

`drwxr-xr-x 28 abc tiny  4096 Apr  6 03:04 .`

How can I login root? and why the user name in prompt `tiny@tty7` still be tiny while in sudo it show the abc's password?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason you got stuck after your edit is that the `/etc/shadow` file contained an entry for the password of `tiny` but no entry for `abc`, whereas the `/etc/passwd` file contained an entry for `abc` and not for `tiny`.  When `sudo` looked, it identified you correctly (according to the password file) as `abc` based on the UID of the process you were running, but when it looked to compare what you entered as your password with the encrypted (hashed) password stored in `/etc/shadow`, it couldn't find an entry for `abc`, so it had to report the failure.

As [shaddy](https://askubuntu.com/users/138269/shaddy) said in his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/605864/6935), don't edit the password or shadow files by hand.  If you must break the rule, then edit both in a single invocation of `vim`, and don't exit from `vim` until you've proved that the changes are sane enough to work by using another terminal window, and do save backup copies of the files before you start hacking them, and do reconsider why you're breaking the rules in the first place, because it probably isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 22):

You must NEVER edit your passwd file manually because you will mess things up.

The proper way to change your username is:

```
usermod -l newUsername oldUsername
```

Then change home folder:

```
usermod -d /home/newHomeDir -m newUsername
```

To change password you should use:

```
sudo passwd yourusername
```

I suggest you to revert your passwd file back, or if you can't edit it because you can not login with root - then boot with live cd and revert the file back. Then use the proper way.

Comment: thank you~  I thought the most difficult is to login with root then I reboot , choose revovery mode , root and then get my passwd file back~ it work~

Answer (score 0):

Use:  vipw

I have always used this on FreeBSD and just confirmed you can use it for Ubuntu too. Please read this page: [Ubuntu Man Page for vipw](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/vigr.8.html)

Answer (score -3):

procedure for changing your username (but not uid) by hand:

1. have your head examined, when that fails proceed to step two.
2. edit shadow file duplicating the user line with new username.
3. edit groups, sudoers, allowing new username permissions, keep old
4. symbolically link home directory to new name
5. edit passwd file changing username and home directory
6. edit shadow, sudoers, groups to remove old entries we kept in step three
7. edit aliases and other references to old username.
8. logout, switch to a text console (the next step will not work if any programs are running in users home directory, including window managers)
9. cd  to a directory above your home directory.
10. remove symbolic link, and rename home directory.
11. logout and login as normal.

Things are much simpler to change others username, although still not simple.